# complements of 'typical of'

Tags: complements, licensing

> "It's typical of men to annex a global trend and turn it into a male
>   device to reject women to make themselves feel clever and us feel
>   stupid."
>  (Helen Fielding, Bridget Jones's Diary)

It seems like in ‘men to annex’ men takes the role of subject and ‘to annex’ predicate. What I want to know is whether these complements of below are all possible.

- It’s typical of men annexing ~
- it’s typical of that men annex ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really two different uses of *typical* here:

> "Men annexing a global trend is typical" ... *ascribes typical occurrence to the **event*** - "Ya see it all the time."
>
> "Annexing a global trend is typical of men" ... *ascribes a typical action to **men*** - "That's typical male behavior."

Each licenses distinct forms:

> It is typical of men
>
> - that they annex a global trend
> - to annex a global trend
>
> It is typical
>
> - that men annex a global trend
> - for men to annex a global trend

But the gerund forms at the top can only appear in subject position.